# Isometric isomorphisms between normed spaces and compact hausdorff spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. Show that there is a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ such that $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $C(Y)$.

I think this might be proved using the Banach–Alaoglu theorem, but I haven't been able to do it.

Is there another result I might need to use?

Comment: Well, you need a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem(s), that $\lVert x\rVert = \sup \{ \lvert \lambda(x)\rvert : \lambda\in X^\ast,\, \lVert\lambda\rVert \leqslant 1\}$, in addition to Alaoglu's theorem.